# How to encode single quote using htmlentites

Tags: php, html-entities

```
            $string="A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
            echo $string;//output-->A 'quote' is bold

            $string=htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            echo $string;//output-->A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

my php version is 5.4.6

i want to encode single quote and  tag

Comment: Can you give an example for this?

Comment: <?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>   try this

Comment: The output is proper. When viewed in a browser, the quotes and `htmlentites()` would appear the same. Check the page source.

Answer (score 0):

try htmlspecialchars

```
<?php
$string="A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
echo $string."<br/>";//output-->A 'quote' is bold

$string=htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
echo $string."<br/>";//output-->A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>

$string=htmlspecialchars($string);
echo $string."<br/>";          
?>
```